# Teach me please - Use the definition of a limit to prove that $\lim_{z \to z_0} Re(z) = Re(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Use the definition of a limit to prove that $$\lim_{z \to z_0} Re(z) = Re(z_0)$$

I know the definition will say $$|Re(z)-Re(z_0)|<\epsilon$$ provided that $$ |z-z_0|<\delta$$
but that's all I've got... I do not feel as though my professor has "taught" this... He's simply said, here is the definition of a limit, now prove this. I'm missing the fundamentals. I don't know what the actual process is here...  I just want some general guidance here. Like teach me how to prove something using the definition of a limit

Comment: As a warmup activity, if I give you $\epsilon = .01$, can you give me a "winning" value of $\delta$?

Comment: Do you take $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to be equal?

Comment: Or should I just go pull out the old calc textbook? bc I have Elementary Analysis and The Complex Variable and Applications texts and these are proving unhelpful

Comment: Yes, that's correct, in this case you can take $\delta$ to be equal to $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$|Re(z)-Re(z_0)|\leq\sqrt{\left(Re(z)-Re(z_0)\right)^2+\left(Im(z)-Im(z_0)\right)^2}=|z-z_0|$$